# ASP.NET MVC SPA - How to handle page refresh in a single page application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I am building a SPA app using ASP.NET MVC.

The entry point of my app is `/home/index`.
All other views will be loaded via ajax.

Now, for example, the user is currently on page `/home/index#/home/widgetdemo`.
When he would hit the refresh button now, the following would happen:
The index view is loaded and right after that, the widgetdemo view is loading.
The problem here is, that the index view is loaded unnecessarily, because on page refresh we want to see the widgetdemo view again. But on the server side I cannot see the hash fragment of the url and cannot know if the user wants the index or the widgetdemo view.

**Now I have a solution in my mind:**

On initial application load or page refresh, check for an existing hash fragment in the url on the client side and load the fragment part instead of index view or if no fragment exists load index view.
This basically loads only the layout page on first load ( or page refresh) and we decide on the client weather to load index view or another view.
-> This results in two requests once.

**What would be best practice here?** (Cookies would be an option, but they would have to be transmitted on every request...)

**EDIT:**

How I do it:
On first page load or page refresh, I only load the Layout page and on document load I examine the url and determine which page/action to fetch/invoke.
It's easy, but you have two requests when the application loads, but then you don't have to mess around with cookies/hiddden fields.

Comment: What client-side framework are you using? Angular?

Comment: no Angular, just jQuery, no framework

Comment: You won't be able to go very far without client-side framework, but it is your call. My suggestion will be to look at Angular2 or ReactJS .Net, before investing times on your own framework.

Comment: Actually everything works nice, just this little "issue".

Comment: Well, if you need to see client side data on the server a common pattern is to add a HiddenFor field whose value can be set client side and then read on server.

Comment: @Win, ok how is it done internally using Angular?

Comment: @Legends ***Angular 2*** uses ***Component Router*** which can handle all the hard works seamlessly that you are currently encountering. Obviously, I could not copy and paste just routing part; you will need to setup plumbing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need I think can be solved by [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) (part of the new HTML5 History API).

Check this nice demo at https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/#pushState-example

Lot of people seem to be using the [`history` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history), but I never tried that directly (I just react-router that ends up using that).

Comment: I think they didn't implement the logic which handles a page refresh in the demo... But with both approaches, history and url fragments, one will have to issue two requests for the initial application load or page refresh.
As the server cannot read history nor fragments. One solution would be cookies or hf which can be read on the server, but you have to implement that logic on the client and server side. So initially having two requests is by far the easiest and the most maintainable approach.

Comment: But using cookies you will always get the last "page/view" the user has visited.  So the next time the users enters your app he will start where he left off, but using one request. But yes, push state is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can always store your current user information on `SessionStorage`/`LocalStorage` and on load check for them to see what should be loaded. However this requires a lot of plumbing to be done.

Of course certain browsers won't support those s

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}


window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('currentPlace', $.urlParam('param1'));

    // ... any other thing you want to store
}

window.onload = function() {

    var param = localStorage.getItem('currentPlace');

    // ... load what you want
}
```

The use of `sessionStorage` vs `localStorage` is based on whether or not you want to maintain the values when the window is closed.

Also instead of that `param1` you can store any other part of the `url`. This was just a sample.

UPDATE:

As per comment (which is right) if you have a fragment of the `url` there would be no need to store anything unless they close the window. However if you load a portion of the page without changing the `url` you can use the above technique to store what part was loaded last.

Comment: If you have a hash fragment in your url, you don't need all the storage stuff, one has just to read the fragment from the url on page load. Your example is good if you want the user to continue where he left oft, when he closes the page using `localstorage`.

Comment: that was an example, usually using ajax you don't update the url, instead you just load the internal content. so you will need to store something to indicate what part has been loaded last @Legends